# How do I factor imacro script?

Tags: refactoring, imacros

I would like to factor code on imacro, my macro looks like that

```
URL GOTO=https://www.exempleurl1.com/
CLICK X=273 Y=503
CLICK X=276 Y=548
CLICK X=863 Y=320
URL GOTO=https://www.exempleurl2.com/
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=NAME:body CONTENT="Hello"
CLICK X=273 Y=503
CLICK X=276 Y=548
CLICK X=863 Y=320
```

Over and over again (20 times)

I would like to use a function to automate all the "CLICKS".
Is there any way to factor my imacro code to make it a lot cleaner ?

Thanks

Comment: Using the 'CLICK' Mode is "dirty" Coding anyway already, no way you can make it "clean", ah-ah...!

Comment: (Just like this Site is "dirty (hum, = buggy!) coded" with its 'Edit' Link which only triggers some "Comments may only be edited for 5 mins" while the "x mins ago" gets dynamically updated IRT...) - + "An error occurred while adding this comment..." several times, ah-ah...!

Comment: I need to use the click mode. The selector name changes every time.

Comment: Mouah, not really a "good" Argument, there are maybe 10 different ways to deal with Dynamic Selectors/ID's, and the 'CLICK' Mode is probably the last one to (or that I would) choose...